# How do I store comparison functions in a Dictionary?

Tags: c#, function, dictionary

I would like to have my comparison functions accessible by using a key. This is what I have tried. I think my problem is how I'm declaring the type for the dictionary value.

```
internal static int CompareUsersByEmail(MembershipUser a, MembershipUser b)
{
    // imagine null checking happening here.
    return string.Compare(a.Email, b.Email, true);
}

public static void Sort(List<MembershipUser> list, string expression) {

    // I can do this
    list.Sort(CompareUsersByEmail);

    // but not this
    Dictionary<string, Func<MembershipUser, MembershipUser, int>> compareFns;
    compareFns = new  Dictionary<string, Func<MembershipUser, MembershipUser, int>>();
    compareFns["Email"] = CompareUsersByEmail;
    list.Sort(compareFns[expression]); // where expression would be "Email"
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I love "is this possible" questions...  have you tried it? You say you have, but you've not specified what went wrong.

Comment: I was getting a build error on the last line due to the value of `compareFns[expression]` being the wrong type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your dictionary type to:

```
Dictionary<string, Comparison<MembershipUser>> compareFns;
```

I believe it will then work with no other changes. The method group conversion to `Comparison<MembershipUser>` will still work, and now you can call `List<T>.Sort(Comparison<T>)`.

Comment: Being psychic gives you a distinct advantage here sometimes.